# Raspbian Password Change Not Working

Tags: ssh, raspbian-buster, headless, password

I'm using Raspbian Buster and I'm using my Raspberry Pi headlessly. After I log in to SSH when I use a new OS image, I always change the password from the default one. I use `sudo passwd` to change the password. Now, when I change my password, everything works successfully but the password doesn't really change, so I have to use `raspbian` when I SSH in next time, even when I've changed the password to something else. How do I change my password so it's recognised?

Comment: How exactly do you change the password?

Comment: It possible that the SD card is failing - how old is the card?

Comment: @Dirk I use `sudo passwd` to change the password.

Comment: @Andyroo The card is three months old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you typed `sudo passwd` without any other arguments, you changed the password of the root user. If you want to change the password of a regular user (for example `pi`), there are two easy ways to do it:

1. Log in as the user and run `passwd` without sudo.
2. Run `sudo passwd pi` to change pi's password. You can replace `pi` with any username that exists on your system.
   I recommend that you use the first option if you're not familiar with the passwd command.